# Has the traffic on this site changed, or have my questions changed?

Tags: discussion, questions, asking-questions, traffic

I joined SO about 4 months ago. Over the first couple months, I asked about 13 questions, all related to iPhone development. I was impressed with how quickly I received responses, and without fail all my questions were being answered.

However, out of the past 10 questions I have asked, I have received only 1 satisfactory/helpful answer. For most of them, after a couple days they had next-to-no views at all. I ended up offering bounties on several of them, just to get some notice... and even with the bounties, I received almost no replies; and none which actually answered my questions.

I can only think of 2 explanations.

1. The type of traffic on the site has changed, so that fewer iPhone people are browsing/posting.
2. My questions have become much more difficult over time.

To me, they seem like mostly the same type/complexity of questions that I used to ask, but perhaps as I have grown in my iPhone skills, the types of questions I now can't figure out on my own are more difficult than the ones I used to ask about.

Any ideas? Am I doing something wrong with how I'm asking my questions? Thanks.

Comment: They're all playing the Farmville app

Comment: I would add possibility 3.) - that the audience in the iPhone tag has changed with the technology's growing popularity, with a  growing proportion of less skilled users, and thus a reduced likelihood for a question to be answered. Or put bluntly, more noobs, less pros. That may not account for all of the phenomenon but surely parts of it

Comment: A good theory. Perhaps the iPhone tag simply has a lot more questions now than it did before; which means my questions don't stand out as much.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it's a combination of factors including:

- I think your questions have changed.  I experienced the same phenomenon myself.  You don't realize that your questions are getting harder but as you learn, they are.
- Also what Pekka said: More less skilled iPhone programmers means the ratio of questions to expert answerers has increased, statistically lowering your questions chances of being *seen*, much less answered.